# powershell add multiple values in custom object

Tags: powershell

I have a variable called $ID which contains the following:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

I have another variable called $name which contains the following:

- name1
- name2
- name3
- name4
- name5

I have a third variable called $IP which contains the following:

- IP1
- IP2
- IP3
- IP4
- IP5

I want to create a custom object called 'ID' and 'Name' and 'IP, which will contains these values in same list order. It should look like below:

- ID    Name    IP
- ...   ....    ....
- 1     name1   IP1
- 2     name2   IP2
- 3     name3   IP3
- 4     name4   IP4
- 5     name5   IP5

Can someone help me achieve this if possible? I have searched all day but nothing worked so far.

PS: You can ignore the bullets. The values are in list formats. When I posted the question, it showed the values in one line instead of the next line.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`for` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for):

```
# figure out the number of objects to produce
$listLength = ($ID.Count,$name.Count,$IP.Count |Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum

# then loop that many times, creating a new object from the next item in each of the 3 arrays
$objects = for($i = 0; $i -lt $listLength; $i++){
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ID   = $ID[$i]
        Name = $name[$i]
        IP   = $IP[$i]
    }
}
```

`$objects` now contains custom objects as described in your question.

Comment: Thank you Mathias, you saved my life. It worked. But I did not understand the code well. I would be grateful if you could provide a brief explanation, specially the for $i section

Comment: @Anonymous I strongly suggest reading the documentation on `for` loops I linked to in the answer. `$i = 0` is only run once, before the loop start. The loop will continue to run as long as `$i -lt $listLength` evaluates to `$true`. Finally, after each iteration, `$i++` is run - so the loop continues running until `$i` reaches the same value as `$listLength`